# Pass, return and convert to vectors list of lists over JNI

Tags: java, c++, list, java-native-interface, stdvector

I need to pass from Java

```
List< List<MyPoint> > points;
```

over jni to C++ and convert to

```
std::vector< std::vector<MyPoint> >
```

Process this vectors and return

```
List< List<MyPoint> >
```

1. How correct pass and return list of lists?
2. How convert list of lists of objects in vector of vectors of objects and backward?

Comment: Have you tried [Swig](http://www.swig.org/), especially [Swig with STL](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library)? It will generate the necessary JNI glue code for you.

Comment: No, the use of Swig in this problem is unacceptable - only standard tools.

Comment: @WdF: Why is it unacceptable? The least you can do is to try Swig out and see what kind of Java/JNI code it generates. Everything that Swig does automatically can be also done using just hand-written code.

Comment: Swig is not naked JNI - it is additional tool. Initially, use the minimum required third-party tools.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved this problem with standard tools.

1. Create in Java class as objects (O) container (C)
2. Pass array of objects (O) from Java code to native part
3. Create from array vector in C++ code
4. Calculate new vectors
5. Build array of containers (C) and insert into objects (O)
6. Return array of containers (C)

**Code implement:**

On java part:

*1 - Create array from list of points*

On c++ part:

*2 - build input vector*

```
std::vector<CurvePoint> src_line;

jclass java_points_cls = env->FindClass("myPointClass");
jmethodID java_mid = env->GetMethodID(java_points_cls, "<init>", "(II)V");    
jfieldID fidX = env->GetFieldID(java_points_cls, "x", "I");
jfieldID fidY = env->GetFieldID(java_points_cls, "y", "I");

int srcCount = env->GetArrayLength(srcLines);

for (int i=0; i < srcCount; i++) 
{
    jobject cur_pnt =  env->GetObjectArrayElement(srcLines, i); 

    LinePoint src_point;        

    src_point.x = env->GetIntField(cur_pnt, fidX); 
    src_point.y = env->GetIntField(cur_pnt, fidY);    

    src_line.push_back(src_point);
}
```

*3 - calculation `lines`*

*4 - build output array*

```
jclass java_line_cls = env->FindClass("myLinesClass");

jmethodID java_line_add = env->GetMethodID(java_line_cls, "addPoint", "(II)V");  
jmethodID java_line_init = env->GetMethodID(java_line_cls, "<init>", "()V");

jobjectArray resLines = (jobjectArray) env->NewObjectArray(lines.size(),     java_line_cls, 0); 

for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
{
    jobject cur_line =  env->NewObject(java_line_cls, java_line_init);
    for(int j = 0; j < lines[i].size(); ++j)
        env->CallVoidMethod(cur_line, java_line_add, 
                                lines[i][j].x,
                                lines[i][j].y);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(resLines, i, cur_line);
}

return resLines;
```

Java part

*5 - Create list of lines from returned array*

Comment: Ok, how is that better than JavaCPP?

Comment: Must be used only standard tools. This is requirement for project. In another case  may be used JavaCpp or SWIG. I find JavaCpp as better variant)

Comment: Ah, I see... Although using the output of SWIG or JavaCPP as reference could still be useful I guess :)

Comment: Hey @George,
I am having same scenario, I have to return from my JNI Vector< Vector<Point> > points to java class.
How can I do this ?

Comment: @DcodeChef, see step (4). I have class "myLinesClass" in Java part. I made array of instances of this class. And this class contain array of points. I push points there with method "addPoint" of this class. So we have vector<Point> in instance of class and vector<vector<Point>> in array of the instances.

Comment: @George Thanks for your answer. If possible, could you include the Java code for `myLinesClass`? To store the `(x,y)` points do you use arrays with primitives (eg: `int[n]`) or lists (eg: `List<Integer>`)? I'm having a hard time figuring out how to define the function `addPoint` :S

Comment: @Jaime Ivan Cervantes, Unfortunately, I've lost this code a lot time ago. It isn't important, how you do realise point store into the Line class. So it may be just another class Point, that has fields x and y. At the same time Line can have only one field with an array of Points and function addPoint, that provides adding new point in the array.

Answer (score 6):

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_ProcessInformation_getAllProcessPid  (JNIEnv*env,jobject obj) {

    vector<string>vec;

    vec.push_back("Ranjan.B.M");

    vec.push_back("Mithun.V");

    vec.push_back("Preetham.S.N");

    vec.push_back("Karthik.S.G");

    cout<<vec[0];

    cout<<vec[0];

    jclass clazz = (env)->FindClass("java/lang/String");

    jobjectArray objarray = (env)->NewObjectArray(vec.size() ,clazz ,0);

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {

        string s = vec[i]; 

         cout<<vec[i]<<endl;

         jstring js = (env)->NewStringUTF(s.c_str());

        (env)->SetObjectArrayElement(objarray , i , js);

    }

    return objarray;    

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As i understand it from the reference the JNI, JNI can only work with one-dimensional arrays of primitive types or objects.

Because on the side of Java, had to translate the list into an array. Then, in the native part the array passed and the number of elements. There's going to the desired vector and processed. Returns as a result of two arrays (array with points all contours and the array with the number of points in each contour) and the number of contours. The resulting array is collected in a list of lists on the side of Java.

While the problem is not solved completely, because the JNI can not allocate memory for an existing item in the native part. Therefore it is necessary to extract the data in part, to allocate memory for them on the side of Java, and fill in the native.

A possible resolve may be the use of binders such as SWIG or JavaCpp

Comment: +1 for [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) :) BTW, we can do in JNI all that can be done in Java, it's just a PITA and really inefficient.

Comment: @SamuelAudet nice work with JavaCPP - i usually work with SWIG, but JavaCPP really looks nice. I have to take a deeper look :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this [project](https://code.google.com/p/android-cpp-sdk/). It will allow to use java classes ower JNI like a native one.