# How to return a vector of float values from JNI to Java?

Tags: java, android

I want to export a vector of float values from the function toGray() to the java code and access the values from there.

**Java :**

```
mRgba = new Mat();
mGray = new Mat();
convertNativeGray(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr(), mGray.getNativeObjAddr())
```

**C++ :**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_ndkoid_MainActivity_convertNativeGray (JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrRgba, jlong addrGray)
Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
Mat& mGray = *(Mat*)addrGray;

// I pass them to a function
conv = toGray(mRgb, mGray)
retVal = (jint)conv;
return retVal;

// Function
int toGray(Mat img, Mat& gray){
    ......... }
```

" [Pass, return and convert to vectors list of lists over JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813346/pass-return-and-convert-to-vectors-list-of-lists-over-jni) " comes close to my question. But I don't quite understand it.

Kindly help me with exporting the float values from function toGray() to the java code.

Thanks!