# how to pass std::list parameter from JNI to call a native c++ function

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am writing a JNI wrapper to call a native c++ method in NFIQ dll.

the method signature is as follows:

```
unsigned int computeQualityScore(
            NFIQ::FingerprintImageData rawImage, 
            bool bComputeActionableQuality, std::list<NFIQ::ActionableQualityFeedback> & actionableQuality,
            bool bOutputFeatures, std::list<NFIQ::QualityFeatureData> & qualityFeatureData,
            bool bOutputSpeed, std::list<NFIQ::QualityFeatureSpeed> & qualityFeatureSpeed);
```

what is the java equivalent parameter to be passed from JNI wrapper class in place of `std::list<NFIQ::QualityFeatureSpeed> & qualityFeatureSpeed` ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: JNI is a C interface. And run javah over your java file to get the native C header generated for you.

Comment: There is no equivalent, you have to do the marshalling yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. are there any C++ interfaces available? @RichardCritten

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how to do that ? @jorn

Comment: @sindhu you would have to convert the Java-`List` into a `std::list` wihtin the C(++) implementation. This would work by e.g. iterating over the Java-`List` and add each element in the list to the `std::list`.

Comment: Will try to do this. Thanks :) @Turing85

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to do a helper in your C++ code that will prepare the wrappers for you.

Here is a sample almost identical to yours (only `std::vector` instead of `std::list`):

[Pass, return and convert to vectors list of lists over JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813346/pass-return-and-convert-to-vectors-list-of-lists-over-jni)